# Finding all isomorphisms between two groups

Tags: group-theory, extension-field, group-isomorphism

My question has its root from the [following one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539002/determining-the-proper-function-for-morphisms).

Consider the following groups: $$\begin{cases}G_{1}=\{x+y\sqrt3|x,y \in \mathbb Q,x^2-3y^2=1 \}\\
G_{2}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}x&3y\\
y&x\\\end{pmatrix}|x,y \in \mathbb Q,x^2-3y^2=1  \right\}\end{cases} $$

What are all the group isomorphisms between those two groups? I was trying to use the fact that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$ is a field extension of $\mathbb Q$... without success.

Comment: $G_1$ is the group of units of $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{3}]$. A theorem by Dirichlet shows that this group is $\{ \pm 1 \} \times \langle u \rangle$, where $u$ is called the fundamental unit. Do you know these facts?

Comment: If you find a single isomorphisms $\tau:G_1 \to G_2$, then the set of all isomorphisms is equal to the set of composites $\tau\alpha$ with $\alpha \in {\rm Aut}(G_1)$. From the structure of $G_1$ described by Crostul, you can see that it has exactly $2$ automorphisms, the identity, and one which maps $u \mapsto u^{-1}$. So there are just two isomorphisms $G_1 \to G_2$.

Comment: @Crostul No I was unaware of this theorem from Dirichlet. Thank you for pointing that up.