# Showing an isomorphism exists between two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For $a, b ∈ \Bbb Z$, let $B(a, b) ∈ M(2, \Bbb Z)$ be defined by $$B(a, b) =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 3b \\
b & a \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $S = \{B(a, b) | a, b ∈ \Bbb Z\} ⊆ M(2,\Bbb Z)$. Show that $S \simeq \Bbb Z[√3] = \{a + b√3 | a, b ∈ \Bbb Z\}$

So to show that this is an isomorphism, I know that I need to find a bijection from $f:S \to \Bbb Z[√3]$ and that it is commutative. But, I don't know how to start doing this generally. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1539530/589.

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$
B(a, b) =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 3b \\
b & a \\
\end{bmatrix}
= a
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+ b
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= aI + b R
$$
Now note that $R^2=3I$.

Comment: So what do I do with these matrix equations then?

Comment: Can I say that $R = \sqrt 3 I$?

Comment: @Nid, not in $M(2, \Bbb Z)$.

Comment: So then I'm assuming that I just use what you wrote above to show that a bijection exists?

Comment: @Nid, yes, and especially for proving that it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You must firstly show that for each number x of Z[√3], there's a unique tuple (a,b) such as x = a + b√a. Then,you just have to create a function which returns the matrix (a 3b, b a) with a given number a + b√3