# Homomorphism of Matrices over Extended Field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, modules

Let $E$ and $F$ be fields such that $E$ is an extension field of $F$
and $[E:F] = n$. Let $M_k(F)$ denote the ring of $k \times k$ matrices over $F$.

Does there exists a homomorphism from $M_k(E)$ to $M_{nk}(F)$?

For the special case of $k = 1$, we can use the following argument:

$E$ is an $n$-dimensional $F$-vector space and $End_{F}(E) \cong M_n(F)$.
For all $a \in E$, let $L_a$ be the map $L_a: E \to E$ given by $L_a(b) = ab.$
Then $E \cong \{L_a \, : \, a \in E\}$ is a subring of $End_{F}(E)$.

Hence there exists an injective homomorphism $\phi: E \to M_n(F)$.

If $k \geq 2$:

$M_k(E)$ is an $M_k(F)$-module.  For all $A \in M_k(E)$,
let $L_A$ be the map $L_A: M_k(E) \to M_k(E)$ given by $L_A(B) = AB$.
Then $M_k(E) \cong \{L_A \, : \, A \in M_k(E)\}$ is a subring of $End_{M_k(F)}(M_k(E))$?
However is it the case that $End_{M_k(F)}(M_k(E)) \cong M_{kn}(F)$?

If $n = 1$, then $E \cong F$.  So $M_k(F)$ is an $M_k(F)$-module.
Then $M_k(F) \cong \{L_A \, : \, A \in M_k(F)\} \cong End_{M_k(F)}(M_k(F))$.

Answer (score 1):

By choosing a basis of $E/F$, we get that $E$ is isomorphic to a subring of $M_n(F)$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/849464/589)).

This implies that every matrix $A\in M_k(E)$ can be written as a block matrix of $M_k(M_n(F)) \cong M_{kn}(F)$ by replacing each entry in $A$ by its matrix form.