# Showing that two rings are homomorphic to one another.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

For $a, b ∈ \Bbb Z$, let $B(a, b) ∈ M(2, \Bbb Z)$ be defined by $B(a, b) = \begin{bmatrix} a & 3b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$.

Let $S = \{B(a, b) | a, b ∈ \Bbb Z\} ⊆ M(2, Z)$. Show that $S \simeq \Bbb Z[√3] = \{a + b√3 | a, b ∈ Z\}$.

So I need to show that these two are homomorphic. I defined a function: $f: S \to \Bbb Z[√3]$. So in order for $f$ to be a homomorphism, by definition, $f(X+Y) = f(X) + f(Y)$ and $f(XY) = f(X)f(Y)$ must be true.

So I took, $X,Y \in S$ and found that $X+Y =\begin{bmatrix} a +c & 3(b+d) \\ b +d & a +c \end{bmatrix} $ and $XY = \begin{bmatrix} ac+3bd & 3(bc+ad) \\ bc+ad & ac+3bd \end{bmatrix} $.

I don't really know where to go from here. I think that $f(X+Y) = (a+c) + (b+d)√3$ and $f(X) + f(Y) = (a +  b√3) + (c +  d√3) = f(X+Y) $.

Next $f(XY) = (ac+3bd) + (bc+ad)√3$ and $f(X)f(Y) = (a +  b√3)(c +  d√3) = ac +3bd + ad√3 + bc√3  = f(XY) $.

In this way it seems that $f$ is a homomorphism but I don't think I can make a lot of the assumptions I did above.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: I feel like you are quite confused or have not presented your thoughts properly. Let $f\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & 3b \\ b & a\end{array}\right)\right) = a+b\sqrt{3}$ and see what happens.

Comment: To see where $f$ comes from: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/849464/589.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I'm not sure I understand what the difference is. I did both and found that say $f((a+b√3) + (c+d√3)) = f(a+b√3) +  f(c+d√3)$ and that $f((a+b√3)(c+d√3)) = f(a+b√3) f(c+d√3)$. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: I guess the point of confusion was that you never stated what $f$ actually was. It just looked like you were mashing variables together. It is hard to tell exactly what you did for this reason.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ok, I understand. I never explicitly defined $f$ but if I define $f$ as what you had said in your comment, would that make it correct?

Comment: Yep. Do make sure to go through the details, though! That is the important part :)

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ok cool. I just figured that if I have to define $f$, then I have to explicitly say how I go from matrix form to what I have in $a+b3√$, so I left it kind of ambiguous. I will do that from now on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this adds some clarity to your thought-process:

Consider $B(a,0) = \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix} = aI$. It should be pretty clear that:

$a \mapsto B(a,0)$ is a homomorphism of $\Bbb Z$ into $S$ (it's actually injective, so we can regard it as an "embedding").

Next, consider $B(0,1) = \begin{bmatrix}0&3\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. Note that $[B(0,1)]^2 = B(3,0)$. Let's call this matrix $R$ (for "radical").

Finally, you can write any element of $S$ as:

$aI + bR$, where $R^2 = 3I$.

You can then use the distributive laws of matrix multiplication to show that:

$\phi: \Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}] \to S$ given by $\phi(a + b\sqrt{3}) = aI + bR$ is an isomorphism.