# Representation of fields with matrices

Tags: matrices, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, cayley-hamilton

I know that the ring

$(AS,+,\cdot)$, where

$$AS := \bigg\{\bigg( \begin{matrix} a & - b \\ b & a \end{matrix} \bigg) \; : \; a,b \in \mathbb{R} \bigg\}$$

and $+$ is the matrix addition and $\cdot$ is the matrix multiplication, is a field and it's isomoprhic to the field of the complex numbers $(\mathbb{C},+,\cdot)$

this is a consequence of the fact that
$AS = \mathbb{R}[J]$ where

$$J = \bigg( \begin{matrix} 0 & - 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \bigg)$$ is a matrix such that
$p_J(t) = t^2 + 1$, which thanks to the Cayley-Hamilton theorem tells me that
$J^2 + I = O$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $O$ is the null matrix. from this it can be seen pretty easily that $AS = \mathbb{R}[J] \cong \mathbb{C}$

I would like to generalize this result, therefore I would like to prove this theorem

**Theorem**

> Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field, let $\mathbb{F}$ be a [simple algebraic extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension) of $\mathbb{K}$ of degree $n$, then there exists a subring $MR$ of the ring $(\mathbb{K}^{n \times n}, + , \cdot)$ such that $MR$ is a field and $MR \cong \mathbb{F}$

So basically I have to prove that there exists a matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ such it's Characteristic polynomial equals the minimal polynomial of the extension $\mathbb{F}$ of $\mathbb{K}$.

More in general, if $q \in \mathbb{K}[t]$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, there exists a matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ such that $p_A(t) = q(t)$ ? If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: Consider the action of $F$ on itself by left multiplication.

Comment: The English term is *degree*, not "grade". The prototype of a matrix $A$ such that $p_A=\mu_A=q$ is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $q$.

Comment: Hint: The ring $R=\mathbb F[t]/\langle q(t)\rangle$ is also a $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F,$ with basis $1,\bar t,\dots,\bar t^{n-1}.$ The map $r\mapsto \bar t r$ is a linear map on $R,$ and thus has a matrix representation over this basis. But that matrix has a characteristic polynomial (and minimal polynomial) $q(x).$

Comment: For example, when $q(t)=t^3-t+1,$ $t^3\equiv t-1,$ and $t(a+bt+ct^2)\equiv (-c)+(c+a)t+bt^2$ and the matrix is: $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849403/embedding-fields-in-matrix-rings

Answer (score 1):

For any polynomial $q(t) = t^n + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} + a_{n-2} t^{n-2} + ... + a_1 t + a_0 \in \mathbb K[t]$ of degree $n$, then
$$
\mathbf A =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
-a_0 & -a_1 & -a_2 & \cdots & -a_{n-2} & -a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is the matrix which $p_{\mathbf A}(t) = q(t)$.

Furthermore, if $\mathbb F = \mathbb K(\theta)$, and $q$ is the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over $\mathbb K$, then we have $\mathbb F \cong \mathrm{span}\{\mathbf I, \mathbf A, \mathbf A^2, \cdots, \mathbf A^{n-1}\}$ over $\mathbb K$